# change ng bootstrap active tab after view initialised

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Please see the following [plunker](http://next.plnkr.co/edit/qmQk6vvT1FdJQlj6)

I want to be able to select a tab after the tabs have been rendered but I get an error ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. The scenario is on refresh of browser if this particular route has an ID value then load the entity and then select the detail tab.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    if(null!=id) {
      this.loadEntity(id);
      this.tabs.select('detail');
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by having a variable selected tab in the component and then setting the activeId of the tabs to this variable.

```
<ngb-tabset [activeId]="selectedTab">
```

In the onInit of the component I then just set this selectedTab variable to the detail tab if the route contains an ID...

```
let id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
if(null!=id) {
  this.loadEntity(id);
  this.selectedTab = 'detail';
}
```